# Having more WCF methods in a service can decrease performance?

Tags: wcf, performance, methods, size, operations

What is a best practice for designing WCF services concerning to the use of more or less operations under a single service.

Taking into consideration that a Service must be generic and Business oriented, I have encountered some SOAP services @ work that have too much XML elements per operation in their contracts and too many operations in a single service.

From my point of view, without testing, I think the number of operations within a service will not have any impact on the performance in the middleware since a response is build specifically for each operation containing only the XML elements concerning that operation.

Or are there any issues for having too many operations within a SOAP service ?

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue, and that is when trying to do a metadata exchange or a proxy creation against a service with many methods (probably in the thousands). Since it will be trying to do the entire thing at once, it could timeout, or even hit an OutOfMemory exception.

Answer (score 0):

Dont hink it will impact performance much but important thing is methods must be logically grouped in different service. Service with large number of method usually mean they are not logically factored.